# Grouping all result by year in MySql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

**I have table in MySql like below**

**ID**  **Name**        **Year_born**

```
1   Manoj       1977

2   Babu        1977

3   Naren       1976

4   Kumar       1977

5   Srikanth    1976

6   Lakshmi     1983
```

**Now I am getting result like below**

```
1   Naren       1976

2   Srikant     1976

3   Manoj       1977

4   Babu        1977

5   Kumar       1977

6   Lakshmi     1983
```

**But, I want as below**

**People born in 1976**

```
1   Naren

2   Srikanth
```

**People born in 1977**

```
1   Manoj

2   Babu

3   Kumar
```

**People born in 1983**

```
1   Lakshmi
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What you have tried ? Show the code

Comment: have you tried group by in mysql?

Comment: try `group by YEAR('your_year_column)`

Comment: try the following code `"SELECT 'ID', 'Name' FROM 'your_table_name' WHERE Year_born = '1976' "`

Comment: Getting 3 results like that would require 3 different selects, which would make it harder than just using the sorted result and do the logic in the presentation layer (ie loop through the result set which is ordered by `Year_born` and output a header with the year every time `Year_born` changes from one line to the next)

Comment: I don't understand what the first column represents

Comment: My query is - "SELECT * FROM names"; but if i use "SELECT * FROM names WHERE year = 1977" i will get who all are born on 1977. But, with single query i want to print all the years and under the year who all are born in that year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $get_year = "SELECT * FROM names GROUP BY YEAR(year) ORDER BY year";
    $year_result = mysqli_query($conn, $get_year);

    while($year_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($year_result)){
        $year = $year_row['year'];
        echo $year;

        $get_year_by = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE year = $year";
        $year_by_result = mysqli_query($conn, $get_year_by);

        while($year_by_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($year_by_result)){
            echo $year_by_row['name'];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select `ID`,`Name` from `table_name` group by `Year_born`,`ID`;
```

Further if you want to order by ID then you can add `order by ID` to above query. This will give you `ID` ordered by smallest to largest.

Similarly if you want to order it by `Name` simply replace `order by ID` to `order by Name`.

`Group By` will show the results in Group format.

Or if you want individual year wise then try below query:

```
select `ID`,`Name` from `table_name` where `Year_born` = '1977';
```

Replace `1977` with whichever year you want to filter.

Comment: The group by looks like it would generate one row per `Year_born` with a random name/id out of that group.

Comment: not random. it will show first one whichever there in that year. but, i want to print all the names with one query. not replacing the year every time.

Comment: @user2099001 the 1st query should work out for  you then.

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
GROUP BY Year_born, ID
ORDER BY Year_born
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name),Year_born FROM table_name GROUP BY Year_born;
```

Comment: i used query as "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM names GROUP BY YEAR(year)".    But, I am getting an error: Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\maliflix-v1\names-group-by-year.php on line 45.

Comment: @user2099001 Try `GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS name, Year_born...`